# java error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and taking the course *Algorithm*, which is provided by Princeton. In the course, professor asked us to download *algs4.jar* to a folder and add *algs4.jar* to the classpath.[1]

I followed it step by step, and try to program a *HelloWorld* like

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;

public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
     StdOut.print("Hello World!");
}
}
```

However when I compile the file, console reminds me that

```
NPP_EXEC: "java_Compile_Run"
NPP_SAVE: G:\java\helloworld\HelloWorld.java
javac -encoding UTF-8 "G:\java\helloworld\HelloWorld.java"
Process started >>>
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)

==========编译成功后开始运行==========
java -cp "G:\java\helloworld" "HelloWorld"
Process started >>>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
edu/princeton/cs/algs4/StdOut
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

I have checked my classpath, and my programming file. What does this error mean? And how can I fix it?

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

---

[1] http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're referring to a jar file that should be on the classpath, you must name it explicitly. E.g.

```
java -cp "G:/java/helloworld;G:/whereever/algs4j.jar" HelloWorld
```

Do they *really* provide another name for `System.out`? In this case you can also safely ignore that jar by using `System.out` instead of `StdOut`

Comment: How do I write this statement in cmd? Thank you.

Comment: well, just as i wrote it in that answer. Your question contains `java -cp "G:\java\helloworld" "HelloWorld"` - however you get there, you'll need to add the jar file that should be on the classpath as well as the directory. You're not mentioning any development tool or anything else that you use apart from javac - if your problem is that you don't know how to configure your IDE, you should state which IDE you're using

Comment: well, guess what $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) gets replaced with and try to see where the additional jar needs to go. Hint: `java -cp "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY);G:/whereever/algs4j.jar" "$(NAME_PART)"` is close, I'll leave the task of knowing where you put the jar to you

Answer (score 7):

According to the [instructions of this course](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/mac/) you should use `javac-algs4` to compile and `java-algs4` to execute if you imported their library.

If you want to know the differences between these two commands and original commands `javac` and `java`, you could

1. use `type` command to find where is this command is
2. use `cat` or `vim` to see what's the content of this command

You can see that `java-algs4` added `-cp` parameter to original `java` command just as Olaf Kock said.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to probably use `-cp` flag to set the class path to include the package.

While using the `-cp` flag, don't forget to include the current working directory using `.`

So, something like `javac -cp thejar.jar:.` should work in linux or `javac -cp thejar.jar;.` should work for windows

Answer (score 4):

For Mac, using M1, `cd` in your folder:

```
javac -classpath ".:./algs4.jar" HelloWorld.java

java -classpath ".:./algs4.jar" HelloWorld
```

Comment: It seems Java 16 now uses a colon instead of semicolon. Or maybe it's because I'm on a Mac. Anyways it was using a classpath whose parts were separated by colons that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I just included a classpath argument in both `javac` and `java` commands like so:

```
javac -classpath ".;drive\path\to\algs4.jar" Hello.java
```

and

```
java -classpath ".;drive\path\to\algs4.jar" Hello
```

Also if you are manually adding the CLASSPATH environment variable, then remember to close and restart the cmd console.

Answer (score 1):

You imported class StdOut in your java code (import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;), you have to tell java how stdOut implement

Accroding to the link you provided (http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/). You have to follow the "Installing the textbook libraries." section to install this lib first.