# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Coursera Princeton Algorithm Course

Tags: java

I can see that this question has been asked before, but I have not found previous answers useful - specifically my issue is following Princeton University's '*Algorithms*' course on Coursera [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1/home/info) and using their `algs4.jar` file to access ostensibly necessary utilities. I have never used Java before but this seemed like such a good course, I'm trying to muddle through rather than switching to a 'worse' course in a language I know. I have also found a thread specifically on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716370/java-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) and a Reddit question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/guzyaw/from_could_not_find_or_load_main_class_to/), which were equally as useless as the other questions which had this problem, but not with the Princeton's `algs4.jar` file.

This is my code, I haven't bothered to finish it but it should run. Before anybody asks, I've commented out everything except the first `if (StdIn.isEmpty())` check and it still gives me all the same compiler/interpreter errors, so this is nothing to do with it being half-finished - `StdIn.isEmpty()` and `StdIn.readString()` are supposed to be provided by `algs4.jar`:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;

class RandomWord
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (StdIn.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Nothing to read.");
            return;
        }

        String curr_selected_word;
        double curr_probability = 0.0;
        int i = 0;

        while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
        {
            String current_string = StdIn.readString();
            System.out.println("> " + current_string);
        }
    }
}
```

Following the advice of previous threads, I compile like this:

```
javac -cp "./algs4.jar" RandomWord.java
```

Which works fine. Running `java RandomWord`, I get this large messy error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/princeton/cs/algs4/StdIn
        at RandomWord.main(RandomWord.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more
```

The accepted answer on the other question was to reference the `.jar` file explicitly, like this:

```
java -cp "C:\Coursera\Algorithms\Part 1\Java Solutions\HelloWorld;C:\Coursera\Algorithms\Part 1\Java Solutions\algs4.jar" RandomWord
```

Which gives me the exact same error. There is also a comment on the Reddit thread that uses the `-classpath` instead of `-cp` flag, which at least gives a different but stranger error:

```
>java -classpath ./algs4.jar RandomWord
Error: Could not find or load main class RandomWord
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RandomWord
```

Putting quotes around the `.jar` filepath, or providing the absolute filepath, all produce the same error.
I Googled this and predictably it is caused by not having a `main` entry-point, but... see code above?

Lastly, the installer for the Coursera course apparently installs some *Bash* commands ([see here](https://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/hello/specification.php)) called `javac-algs4` and `java-algs4` which is supposed to sort out all this classpath nonsense for me. So I crack open *Bash*, and:

```
>javac-algs4 RandomWord.java
'javac-algs4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have restarted since running the installer. I would add these to my `PATH` manually, but I don't even know where they are; the `C:\Program Files\LIFT-CS` folder that their installer installs into only contains a pissing *uninstaller*. So I'm absolutely losing my rag and at my wits' end after spending over 7 hours just trying to *start* this course, not even getting stuck on the problems or the content. When will content creators learn we don't want your in-house IDE with no dark mode and libraries that do nothing but rename every function to camel-case?

Anyway, if anyone has encountered this or knows what I could do to fix it, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if there is a `RandomWord.class` file after compilation step?

Comment: Hello, yes, compilation is successfully producing a `RandomWord.class` file - that was one of the first things I checked, because I don't know Java at all so I wasn't sure if compilation could silently fail or something.

Comment: Is the code in your question your actual code? If you have written a file named `RandomWord.java`, then the class should be a `public` class, i.e. you should write `public class RandomWord {` rather than just `class RandomWord {` Also, is there a `package` statement in file `RandomWord.java`? For example, the _package_ for class `StdIn` is `edu.princeton.cs.algs4`

Comment: @Abra Yes, it is. I have made the class public and added `package edu.princeton.cs.algs4;` at the top of my code - the result is the same (`Error: Could not find or load main class RandomWord
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RandomWord`)

Comment: I only asked if class `RandomWord` has a "package" statement. I didn't mean that it **must** have a "package" statement. Remove the "package" statement. Maybe try learning java from Oracle's [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -
`javac -cp .;<insert class path> RandomWord`

I was facing the exact same issue, I ran `javac -cp .;.lift/algs4.jar RandomWord` and it works. (My compiled class was in the same directory as `.lift`)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on a Mac. Copy algs4.jar to the root of your project, then:

```
javac -cp ".:./algs4.jar" RandomWord.java 
java -cp ".:./algs4.jar" RandomWord
```